# converting kinect 1.0 game to kinect 2.0

Tags: c#, kinect

I am trying to convert program that is working in kinect 1.0 to kinect 2.0. It looks like raw skeleton data is too far different for straight implementation. 
Any ideas of what is the difference in the data and how to solve that problem will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is quite ambiguous I can only give you a general answer. I recently had to convert an app written with Kinect SDK v1.x to an app with the next gen Kinect sensor and therefore Kinect SDK for Windows v2.x.

There is no problem really. Objects are named differently and behave slightly differently. So you can't just reference new SDK and fix namespaces, but in general the idea is pretty much the same.

So there is no more `SkeletonStream`, but there is [BodyFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.bodyframe.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) class now.

Here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730842/Kinect-for-Windows-version-Color-depth-and-infra) of usage of Color, Depth and Infrared "streams" from CodeProject.

If you can add more details on what exactly you are trying to archive maybe I could assist you better.

I hope it was helpful.